# How to get if in which interval an index exists using set<pair<int, int>>

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search, lower-bound, upperbound

I have `std::set<std::pair<int, int>> intervals` which it's values are some intervals, it is somthing similar to this:

```
{ 0, 5 },
{ 5, 8 },
{ 8, 10 }
```

and I have a number `x` can I find in which interval it is using `lower_bound` or `upper_bound`?

I need a solution with `O(log(N))` complexity.

Because I remember that I saw someone doing it someway like this:

```cpp
int x;
std::set<std::pair<int, int>> intervals;
cin >> x;
auto ans = intervals.upper_bound({ x, INF })
```

and I don't remember what was the value of `INF`

**Note:** the intervals aren't intersecting.

Comment: Do you remember what [`INF`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity) is short for? (Don't you wish people did not abbreviate names?)

Comment: I’d use a vector or an array, holding the boundary values 0, 5, 8, and 10. `std::lower_bound` will have logarithmic time complexity.

Comment: use {x, INT_MAX} and upper_bound will find the next interval, then just back to x's interval. some code not elegant, https://godbolt.org/z/h97P5jMEh

Comment: @JaMit I remember INF was something either INT_MAX or INT_MIN, anyway, thanks to everybody

Comment: Thanks @che.wang !! If your comment was an answer, I'm gonna accept it!!

Comment: @Muaath *"I remember INF was something either INT_MAX or INT_MIN"* -- I'm pretty sure that "INF" is not an abbreviation for either of those. The correct answer is that "INF" is short for "infinity". Once you know that, choosing between the biggest representable integer and, well, any other integer value should be a piece of cake. ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to have a set of continuous ranges, you should simply represent them as a set that keeps only the beginning of each range.

```
set<int> boundaries { 0, 5, 8, 10 };
```

If you really want to use a structure that keeps both ends of a range, the following will allow you to search in `O(log(N))`. In the case of keeping both ends, it is possible to express other than continuous ranges set, so this example intentionally omits [6, 8). If the structure keeps both ends, it is also possible to express overlapping ranges set. In that case, we would have to search for more than one range. I left that example out.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <numeric>
#include <set>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    set<pair<int, int>> intervals{ { 0, 5 },
                                   { 5, 6 },
                                   { 8, 10 } }; // drop {6, 8} version.
    {
        constexpr auto INF = numeric_limits<int>::max();
        auto find = [&](const int x) {
            auto next = intervals.upper_bound({ x, INF });
            if (next != intervals.begin()) {
                if (auto ans = prev(next); x < ans->second)
                    return ans;
            }
            return intervals.end();
        };
        for (int x = -1; x <= 11; ++x) {
            if (auto ans = find(x); ans != intervals.end()) {
                printf("%d is in [%d, %d)\n", x, ans->first, ans->second);
            } else {
                printf("%d is not in any range\n", x);
            }
        }
    }

    set<int> boundaries{ 0, 5, 8, 10 };
    {
        auto find = [&](const int x) {
            auto next = boundaries.upper_bound(x);
            if (next != boundaries.begin()) {
                return prev(next);
            }
            return boundaries.end();
        };

        for (int x = -1; x <= 11; ++x) {
            if (auto ans = find(x); ans != boundaries.end()) {
                if (auto nx = next(ans); nx != boundaries.end()) {
                    printf("%d is in [%d, %d)\n", x, *ans, *nx);
                } else {
                    printf("%d is in [%d, inf)\n", x, *ans);
                }
            } else {
                printf("%d is in [-inf, %d)\n", x, *boundaries.begin());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

stdout is here.

```
// == set<pair<int, int>>
-1 is not in any range
0 is in [0, 5)
1 is in [0, 5)
2 is in [0, 5)
3 is in [0, 5)
4 is in [0, 5)
5 is in [5, 6)
6 is not in any range
7 is not in any range
8 is in [8, 10)
9 is in [8, 10)
10 is not in any range
11 is not in any range

// == set<int>
-1 is in [-inf, 0)
0 is in [0, 5)
1 is in [0, 5)
2 is in [0, 5)
3 is in [0, 5)
4 is in [0, 5)
5 is in [5, 8)
6 is in [5, 8)
7 is in [5, 8)
8 is in [8, 10)
9 is in [8, 10)
10 is in [10, inf)
11 is in [10, inf)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following method where the search range is specified as {x,x+1} we can get the required pair even when the pair ranges are a mix of overlapping and non-over-lapping ones in O(log(n)) using set.find() method.  This uses a custom comparator.

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;
typedef pair<int, int> Range;
struct RangeCompare
{
    bool operator()(const Range& lhv, const Range& rhv) const
    {
        return ((lhv.first <= lhv.second) && (lhv.first < rhv.first) && (lhv.second < rhv.second) && (rhv.first <= rhv.second));
    }
};


auto at_range(const set<Range, RangeCompare>& ranges, int value)
{
    return ranges.find(Range(value, value + 1)) ;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2) {
      cout << "usage:<exe><search number>" << endl;
      exit(1);
    }
    //set<Range, RangeCompare> ranges = {{5,8},{11,14},{0,5},{8,11},{14,17},{20,23},{17,20},{6,8}};
    //set<Range, RangeCompare> ranges = {{5,8},{8,11},{11,14},{20,23},{40,51},{61,81}};
    set<Range, RangeCompare> ranges = {{5,10},{8,12},{10,14},{20,23},{40,51},{61,81}};

    int search = stoi(argv[1]);
    auto ret = at_range(ranges,search);
    if( ret != ranges.end())
      cout << ret->first << ' ' << ret->second <<'\n';
    else
      cout << "Value not found" << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the O(log n) runtime the OP was looking for. Creating a custom struct/class is a matter of syntax, it has nothing to do with the algorithm.

Comment: @Sneftel Thanks!  I have used a simple binary search using the first of the pair value since the set itself sorts the pairs using the first of the pair values.  It should produce the required result in O(log(n)) operations.

Comment: That doesn’t quite do it AFAICT… `advance` has linear time complexity.

Comment: @Sneftel  Modified my code earlier to have a custom compare and set.find() to get the required pair that has the required search value.  This should satisfy the O(log(n)) requirement.

Comment: The `RangeCompare` there works as long as intervals are non-intersecting (though the third test is unnecessary). `std::set::lower_bound` would be an easier fit than `find()` because then you wouldn't need the custom comparator.

Comment: The reason I have the third test to stop returning an iterator for a invalid pair like {23, 22}.  Any pair whose first value is greater than second is invalid and should not be returned. I tried using set::lower_bound without custom compare and it did not quite work even with sample test.  I agree with using the set::lower_bound instead of set::find even with custom compare though.

Comment: The latest changes allow for overlapping and non-overlapping pair ranges. This happens only if set::find is used and the searched pair is {x,x+1} using the custom comparator.